# Team Services Continuous Integration with GitHub Feature Branch

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Friends,

I have a situation where my client created a feature branch in GitHub and we need to setup continuous delivery to the staging environment from this feature branch.

I am using Team Services to build and deploy an ASP.Net application to Azure App Service - Web App. While setting up the build definition in Team Services, I am not getting any non master branches in the dropdown.

Is there any way to setup CI CD with Team Services using non master GitHub branches?

Comment: It is working fine for me. (create a new branch (Dev) in a repository in GitHub=>Create a new build definition with GitHub repository type=>Select Dev branch in Default Branch list), You can clear Internet browser's cache and create a new build definition, then check the result.

Comment: Thanks starain-MSFT. You made my day. Thanks a lot. Not sure - why it gets stuck to master only for the first time. Anyway, my 2nd definition is able to see all branches.

Comment: So your issue has been solved? I post an answer, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks ..yes it solved that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these ways to solve the issue:

1. Create a new branch in a repository in GitHub
2. Create a new build definition with GitHub repository type
3. Select branch in Default Branch list